# How to make API Call from server side instead of Client Side with Angular universal?

Tags: angular, express, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I am using angular 14 with angular universal to do Server side rendering. I would like to know how to make an API Call/request on the server side instead of client side with universal so as not to expose API Request on the client side?

Comment: What backend stack are you using? In ASP.NET Core we have a [`SupplyData`](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/blob/master/MintPlayer.Web/Services/SpaPrerenderingService.cs#L143) method we can use to retrieve and pass data to angular during SSR

Comment: @Pieterjan the one that angular Universal by default provide i-e express.js / node.js

Comment: Do you want to completely hide all sorts of information related to api calls from your angular application or just want to ensure that the calls are being made from server?

Comment: @RadowanMahmudRedoy i want the calls to be made from the server as well

Comment: When you write a api call in any angular service and call it on render it will automatically be called from the server side. Next as the request reaches the client side the browser then will also make a call. If you want to stop the browser call you can use transferstate to ensure that the calls are only made from server.

Comment: @Ahsan "not to expose API Request" But if you navigate to another page, the browser will need to send an ajax call anyway. You just need to make sure your backend is secure

Answer (score 0):

When application runs on server side it makes API calls already because it needs data to render page. You can avoid making same api calls when application bootstraps in browser by using TransferState https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/TransferState
Server side part can pass data from api to client side part of your application so you can check if data from server side is available you can skip calling api on client side.

Also there is an [article](https://medium.com/@haseebahmad109/angular-universal-transfer-state-19a46b315dec) with good explanation.

For angular 16 there is new thing Hydration which can be used as well. Check documentation https://angular.io/guide/hydration

Comment: Thanks for your response, i did GET Api calls using this way and working fine, but unable to do so for the POST and other calls